# Visual Studio 2015: IntelliSense claims it cannot find file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Pretty standard Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.
Project type is a Solution with several class libraries and one Unit test project.

When buildingthe Solution, Intellisense give the following errors:

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'd:\Source\Workspaces\QA\NewMySite\Tests\RegressionTests\Ordering\Ordering.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'd:\Source\Workspaces\QA\NewMySite\Tests\RegressionTests\Ordering\Ordering.cs'.
```

However, the file is there. It's the file I'm currently working on.

First it coplained about not finding UnitTest1.cs i the same location, plus another location. Not strange, since I allways rename the default files. So I figured it's missed my renaming of the default file. So I tried renaming back and forth, resulting in VS hanging crashing completely, needing a restart.

After the restart, it started complaing about not finding the file above, which is 100% certainly there.

Any ideas? The diagnostic tool in Debug mode keeps "failing unexpectedly", and this issue with Intellisense is the only strange thing I've found when troubleshooting. The solution compiles, though, and there doesn't seem to be any other problems except for the debugging.

Comment: Try closing the solution, deleting (or renaming if you're nervous) the .vs folder in the solution directory, and reopening the solution. It's a Visual Studio cache.

Comment: Thanks. That accomplished the following: Intellisense is now gone as an option in the Output window. Also, the diagnostic tool still fails "unexpectedly".

Comment: @FrankH., for the intellisense error, please have a try with 1: clean up all folders and files under the folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ and restart the VS 2015 to check it again 2: Exit VS, delete all non-project files (bin, obj. .vs, _ReSharper.Caches folders, *.suo files, ...), start VS and rebuild 3: Repair VS 2015. For the diagnostic tool failed unexpected, please check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/07/24/no-such-interface-supported-in-visual-studio-2015-on-windows-10/